# Model Binding RazorPage Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

So I am still relatively new to Asp.Net framework experimenting with Razor Pages. I am facing the issue with model binding. It seems to be not working as expected.

This is my razor page. On the "OnGet" action, I am dynamically building a form. Just for some context, the form will have about three kind of inputs, text input, date input, select and multi-select input. The `QueryField` class basically represents each input type. The `Name` attribute represents the name of the parameter, `Required` represents whether the field is required and etc...

```
namespace ReportViewer.Pages
{

    public class QueryField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class ReportModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly AlertService _alertService;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public Report Report {get; set;}

        [BindProperty]
        public List<QueryField> Fields { get; set; }

        public ReportModel(AlertService alertService, ApplicationDbContext dbContext){
            _alertService = alertService;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            Fields = new List<QueryField>();
        }
        
        public void OnGet(string reportName)
        {
            var report = _dbContext.Report.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Name == reportName);

            if (report == null){
                _alertService.AddAlert($"{reportName} is not a valid report. Please check your report name and try again", AlertType.Danger);
            } else {
                Report = report!;
                var parameters = _dbContext.Parameter.Where( p=> p.ReportId == report.Id).ToList();

                foreach (var parameter in parameters){
                    string FieldType;
                    if (parameter.ValidValues.Count() == 0){
                        if (parameter.ParameterType == "Integer"){
                            FieldType = "NumberInput";
                        } else if (parameter.ParameterType == "DateTime"){
                            FieldType = "DateInput";
                        } else {
                            FieldType = "TextInput";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (parameter.MultiValue){
                            FieldType = "MultiSelectInput";
                        } else {
                            FieldType = "SelectInput";
                        }
                    }
                    
                    QueryField field = new QueryField(){
                        Name = parameter.Name,
                        Label = parameter.Name,
                        Type = FieldType,
                        Required = parameter.Nullable,
                        Values = parameter.ValidValues,
                    };

                    Fields.Add(field);
                }
            }
        }

        public  IActionResult OnPost(List<QueryField> formData)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid){
                return Page();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Fields: {formData.Count}");
            return RedirectToPage("Report");
        }

    }
}
```

On the html template..

```
@page "/Reports/{reportName}"
@model ReportViewer.Pages.ReportModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ReportQuery";
}

@if (Model.Report != null){
    <form data-parsley-validate role="form" id="DUBulkStatementReportForm" method="post">
        <p>
            Please enter/select required detail(s)<br>
            <em><small>Fields marked<span style="color: red">*</span> are required</small></em>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>@Model.Report.Name Parameters</h3>
                <hr class="inner-separator" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @if (Model.Fields != null)
                    {
                        // --- render form fields here..
                        @foreach (var field in Model.Fields)
                        {
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @if (field.Type == "NumberInput")
                                {
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="@field.Name" />
                                }
                                else if (field.Type == "DateInput")
                                {
                                    @if (field.Required)
                                    {
                                        <p class="required">@field.Label</p>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <p>@field.Label</p>
                                    }
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control dateP" name="@field.Name">
                                    </div>
                                }
                                else if (field.Type == "TextInput")
                                {
                                    @if (field.Required)
                                    {
                                        <label for="@field.Name" class="form-control required">@field.Label</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="@field.Name" required name="@field.Name" />
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <label for="@field.Name" class="form-control">@field.Label</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="@field.Name" name="@field.Name" />
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                else if (field.Type == "MultiSelectInput")
                                {
                                    @if (field.Required)
                                    {
                                        <p class="required">@field.Label</p>
                                        <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" multiple name="@field.Name" required>
                                            @foreach (var value in field.Values)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@value">@value</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <p>@field.Label</p>
                                        <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" multiple name="@field.Name">
                                            @foreach (var value in field.Values)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@value">@value</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    }

                                }
                                else if (field.Type == "SelectInput")
                                {
                                    @if (field.Required)
                                    {
                                        <p class="required">@field.Label</p>
                                        <select name="@field.Name" class="select2" required>
                                            @foreach (var value in field.Values)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@value">@value</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <p>@field.Label</p>
                                        <select name="@field.Name" class="select2">
                                            @foreach (var value in field.Values)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@value">@value</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    }

                                }
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button id="PrintPDF" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="display:inline">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><b>Download PDF</b>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="PrintEXCEL" class="btn btn-success" style="display:inline">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i><b>Download EXCEL</b>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!--Download PDF Confirmation Modal-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="DownloadPDFReportModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
                        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o success"></i> Download
                                        {{report.name}} Confirmation</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p><strong>Are you sure you want to continue downloading report?</strong></p>
                                    <p>Click No if you would like to cancel. Click Yes to continue.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        id="ConfirmDownloadPdf">Yes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End of PDF Confirmation Modal-->

                    <!--Download EXCEL Confirmation Modal-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="DownloadEXCELReportModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
                        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o success"></i> Download
                                        {{report.name}} Confirmation</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p><strong>Are you sure you want to continue downloading report?</strong></p>
                                    <p>Click No if you would like to cancel. Click Yes to continue.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        id="ConfirmDownloadExcel">Yes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End of EXCEL Confirmation Modal-->

                    <!--Download Wait Modal-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="ReportDownloadWaitModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
                        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title text-success"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o success"></i>
                                        Downloading File...</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body text-success" id="successMessage">
                                    <p>Please wait while the file is being downloaded...</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End of Download Wait Modal-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

}
```

The form renders fine. The issue I am having is on the `OnPost` action handler. I would expect that if the binding works as expected, the Fields would be populated but that does not seem to be the case. In this case printing `formData.Count` gives me 0 indicating that
the perhaps the binding did not work. However, I can see the form data in the Request if I call `Request.Form["field_name"]`. I would prefer to go with the binding approach instead of parsing the data from the Request object.

I am not sure what I am missing or whether I am doing things the right way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the result of `List<QueryField> formData`?

Comment: Its empty. The count is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the name attribute like :`name="formData[@i].Name"` to bind the name value to OnPost(List `formData`)  (QueryField Name).

You can try to remove  `@foreach (var field in Model.Fields)` and add  `@for (var i = 0; i< Model.Fields.Count; i++ )` like:

```
 @if (Model.Fields != null)
  {
      @for (var i = 0; i< Model.Fields.Count; i++ )
 
   {
     // --- render form fields here..
         <div class="form-group">
         @if (Model.Fields[@i].Type == "NumberInput")
             {
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="formData[@i].Name" />
             }
         else if (Model.Fields[@i].Type == "DateInput")
             {
             @if (Model.Fields[@i].Required)
                 {
                 <p class="required">@Model.Fields[@i].Label</p>
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 <p>@Model.Fields[@i].Label</p>
                 }
                 <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                     </span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control dateP" name="formData[@i].Name">
                 </div>
             }
          ...
```

Remember change the `field` into  `Model.Fields[@i]`. Then we can get the `List<QueryField> formData`  like:
[image]

**Note** We will meet the ModelState.IsValid is false, because the other properties in QueryField is not pass to the Post method.